# Selecting a Good, Better, Best suggestion from Best Selling Products in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have two tables:

`Products` and `SalesRecords`

From this I can create a simple SQL statement to get me the top 100 best selling products

```
SELECT p.item, p.price, COUNT(s.itemId) 
    FROM
    SalesRecords s 
    LEFT JOIN Products p ON p.id=s.itemId
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY COUNT(s.itemId) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

*(Incidentally, I am selecting from SalesRecords and then JOINing Products as I found it to be much faster than the other way around - I'd like to know why, but that's not the primary question!)*

Hopefully, the Database Schema is clear enough from that to know what is going on. We have a `ID` column in `Products` which relates to the `itemId` column in `SalesRecords`, join the tables on these relations and then sort by how many times each product row appears in SalesRecords.

What I want to be able to do now, is re-order that list by price and split it into three sections, then randomly return two rows from each of the three sections.

The intended result being:

- Two Items from the top third of prices
- Two Items from the middle third
- Two Items from the bottom third

Thus returning a Good, Better, Best suggestion of products from the top sellers.

(In practice there'll be other WHERE clasues etc to make this more relevant, but the basis of the query is what I need)

Is this possible with SQL? (MySQL)

Comment: Oh, bugger, missed it, sorry. Will update immediately

Comment: OK. But consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. It's always clearer that way

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i get what you want correctly, but.

This is your sql with where clause rather then left join (i hope you dont have nulls)

```
SELECT p.item, p.price, COUNT(s.itemId) 
FROM SalesRecords AS s,Products AS p
WHERE p.id = s.itemid
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY COUNT(s.itemId) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

So, above query returns a table which you need.But you want it to be ordered by prices.

```
SELECT p.item, p.price 
FROM ( "put your above query here" )
ORDER BY p.price DESC
```

This will sort your query by prices.

I think we should add row numbers for your selection operation.

```
SET @rownumber := 1; 
SELECT @rownumber := @rownumber + 1 AS rownum , p.item, p.price 
FROM ( "put above query ordered by price" );
```

This will return a table with 100 rows of best items ordered by prices and the indexes of this list. Now i guess, you want to select first 2 best (index with 1,2) , 2 from middle ( index with 51,52) and 2 from bottom (indexes with 99,100)

```
SET @rownumber := 1; 
SELECT @rownumber := @rownumber + 1 AS rownum , p.item, p.price 
FROM ( "put above query ordered by price" );
WHERE rownum = 1 OR rownum = 2 OR rownum = 50 OR row num = 51 ....
```

This queries are seem highly inefficient and might cause table crashes. You might wanna create a WIEV in you database which is a derived virtual table. This new table will your best 100 items ordered by prices with row indexes (and updated frequently). if you use select itemid where rowindex is 1,2,51,...  in that VIEW, it would be much safer. Of course you will need this only if when your system overload the db in future.

Also VIEWs can be very handy to use when you need advanced strict mysql queries.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly want random rows from the top third, middle, and bottom third.  What happens if you don't have 100 items?

The place to start is by counting the number of items actually returns and also enumerating them.  You can do this with variables.  After the first pass, the variable `@rn` will contain the number of returned values, so this query takes advantage of that.  The following assigned the price group to each row:

```
SELECT ps.*, floor((rn*3 - 1)/ @rn) as pricegroup
FROM (SELECT p.item, p.price, COUNT(s.itemId) as cnt, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
      FROM SalesRecords s LEFT JOIN
           Products p
           ON p.id=s.itemId CROSS JOIN
           (select @rn := 0) const
      GROUP BY p.id 
      ORDER BY COUNT(s.itemId) DESC
      LIMIT 100
     ) ps;
```

Next, you want to get two random ids from each one.  This is a pain in MySQL.  Here is a method where the `id`s are concatenated:

```
SELECT floor((rn*3 - 1)/ @rn) as pricegroup,
       substring_index(group_concat(p.item order by rand()), ',', 2) as randitems
FROM (SELECT p.item, p.price, COUNT(s.itemId) as cnt, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
      FROM SalesRecords s LEFT JOIN
           Products p
           ON p.id=s.itemId CROSS JOIN
           (select @rn := 0) const
      GROUP BY p.id 
      ORDER BY COUNT(s.itemId) DESC
      LIMIT 100
     ) ps
GROUP BY floor((rn*3 - 1)/ @rn);
```

Finally, we can join back to get the fuller information:

```
SELECT p.*, pricegroup
FROM (SELECT floor((rn*3 - 1)/ @rn) as pricegroup,
             substring_index(group_concat(p.item order by rand()), ',', 2) as randitems
      FROM (SELECT p.item, p.price, COUNT(s.itemId) as cnt, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
            FROM SalesRecords s LEFT JOIN
                 Products p
                 ON p.id=s.itemId CROSS JOIN
                 (select @rn := 0) const
            GROUP BY p.id 
            ORDER BY COUNT(s.itemId) DESC
            LIMIT 100
           ) ps
      GROUP BY floor((rn*3 - 1)/ @rn)
     ) pg join
     products p
     on find_in_set(p.item, pg.randitems);
```

These operations would not be recommended on large data.  However, you are limited the data to 100 rows, so the performance should be pretty reasonable.